# jqGrid autoencode does not work with add/edit popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I have a jqGrid with add/edit feature. To prevent cross site scripting, I use the autoencode feature. I look at the data being passed in the beforeSubmit and afterSubmit methods and I see the encoding working just fine. But when I close the popup by clicking save, the script executes anyways. The afterComplete method shows the script I had typed without any encoding.

The behavior can be replicated in the demo page too http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html (Live data manipulation -> add/edit row)

Please let me know if there is something obvious I missed or if there any other ways I can prevent this scenario

Comment: Found a solution in case someone else runs into this issue
Do not set autoencode to true but manually encode data in beforesubmit 

 beforeSubmit: function(postdata, formid){               
                jQuery.each(postdata,function(n,v){
                      postdata[n] = jQuery('<div/>').text(v).html();
                });

                return[true, ""];
            }

(This is for 5.0.1 version)

Answer (score 0):

I would don't recommend you to use old 4.6 version of jqGrid (used i). It has many old bugs, which don't are fixed in later versions of jqGrid. [The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/formEditOnDoubleClick-jqueryui-fa.htm) uses for example, free jqGrid 4.13.6 with . You can easy verify, that one can place some code, like `<script>alert("Hello!");</script>` in the column `Client`, for example, data during form or inline editing without executing the script. The data will be saved locally in internal `data` as the string `'<script>alert("Hello!");</script>'`, but the data will be encoded with respect of `$.jgrid.htmlEncode` *before placing the data on the HTML page*. As the result, no script executing will take place if `autoencode: true` is specified.

Comment: I'm using the 5.0.1 version. Should I go back to the old version?

Comment: @user3865946: there are **two** main **alternative forks** of jqGrid now. The first one id "free jqGrid", which I develop and can be used for free under old MIT license. "Guriddo jqGrid JS" is **commertial** version, which prices and license agreement can be found [here](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334). Both forks are based on jqGrid 4.7. Both use absolutely independent version numeration. Free jqGrid uses always 4.x.y version to stress the compatibility with 4.x versions of jqGrid till 4.13.6. The first versions of Guriddo was 4.7.1, 4.8, 5.0.0, 5.0.1, ... 5.2.0.